How can display a custom message under the inputs field when a user clicks on submit while empty
I have a form with five inputs with with two text fields one password field one email field and the other is a submit button and i want the form not to submit when the the fields are empty and also display first name cannot be empty, last name cannot be empty,email cannot be empty and password cannot be empty under each corresponding fields and also check if the email is in a right format .
I tried the code below expecting to display the messages in the p elements when the field is empty but instead the browser refreshes the page with displaying the message in the p elements


fname = document.querySelector("#first-name");
lname = document.querySelector('#last-name');
email = document.querySelector('#email');
password = document.querySelector("#password");

function formValidator() {
  if (fname.value = '') {
    document.getElementById('first-p').innerHTML = "First name cannot be empty"
  };
  if (lname.value = '') {
    document.getElementById('last-p').innerHTML = 'Last name cannot be empty'
  };
  if (email.value = '') {
    document.querySelector('#email-p').innerHTML = 'Email cannot be empty'

  };
  if (password.value = '') {
    document.querySelector('#password-p').innerHTML = 'Password cannot be empty'

  }


}
<form action="">
  <label for="first-name">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name">
  <p id="first-p"></p>
  <br>
  <label for="last-name">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="last-name">
  <p id="last-p"></p>
  <br>
  <label for="Email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="" id="email">
  <p id="email-p"></p>
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="" id="password">
  <p id="password-p"></p>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="formValidator()">
</form>




You aren't doing anything to stop the form from being submitted.

Why not just use the built-in required attribute?

Use the required attribute. Never use the submit button click but instead use the form's submit event - in this case not needed if you use required

What can i do to prevent the form from being submitted

All you have to do is to add required attribute to your inputs. no need to js.
for example:
<input type="email" required id="email">

required uses browsers default validation, which varies by the inputs type
Hope I helped.

First thing: As @mplungjan mentioned, you should be using the required attribute  in the input fields.
Second: Sometimes we do things in our own way. So below is something you might try. I hope it will help.
You can try below:


fname = document.getElementById("first-name");
lname = document.getElementById('last-name');
email = document.getElementById('email');
password = document.getElementById("password");


function formValidator() {
    if (fname.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById('first-p').innerHTML = "First name cannot be empty";
    }
    if (lname.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById('last-p').innerHTML = 'Last name cannot be empty';
    }
    if (email.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById('email-p').innerHTML = 'Email cannot be empty';

    }
    if (password.value.length == 0) {
      document.getElementById('password-p').innerHTML = 'Password cannot be empty';
    }
}
<form action="" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); formValidator();">
  <label for="first-name">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name">
  <p id="first-p"></p>
  <br>
  <label for="last-name">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="last-name">
  <p id="last-p"></p>
  <br>
  <label for="Email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="" id="email">
  <p id="email-p"></p>
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="" id="password">
  <p id="password-p"></p>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitform">
</form>



I hope it will help. Thank you.

A form by default on a submit refreshes the page
To prevent this, use event.preventDefault()
function formValidator(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //the rest of your code

<form onsubmit="formValidator(event)">
<!--eveything else the same-->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



move onsubmit to form element,
return false from formValidator in case of you wat to stop the submit to continue.
replace = with == operator in all your 'if' statement

correct code is given below
   <form onsubmit="return formValidator()">
    <label for="first-name">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-name">
    <p id="first-p"></p>
    <br>
    <label for="last-name">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="last-name">
    <p id="last-p"></p>
    <br>
    <label for="Email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="" id="email">
    <p id="email-p"></p>
    <br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="" id="password">
    <p id="password-p"></p>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>

    <script>
    fname = document.querySelector("#first-name");
    lname = document.querySelector('#last-name');
    email = document.querySelector('#email');
    password = document.querySelector("#password");

    function formValidator() {
    let isError = false;
    if (fname.value == '') {
        document.getElementById('first-p').innerHTML = "First name cannot be empty"
        isError = true;
    };
    if (lname.value == '') {
        document.getElementById('last-p').innerHTML = 'Last name cannot be empty'
        isError = true;
    };
    if (email.value == '') {
        document.querySelector('#email-p').innerHTML = 'Email cannot be empty'
        isError = true;
    };
    if (password.value == '') {
        document.querySelector('#password-p').innerHTML = 'Password cannot be empty'
        isError = true;
    }

        if (isError) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    </script>


Use the build-in form validation instead of creating your own.
The form will only submit if all the required form fields are valid. On the invalid event you can set the class name of the input to something that makes a CSS selector match. And then remove the class name again when the input event happens, and after testing that the field is valid.


document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
});
input~p {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input.invalid~p {
  visibility: visible;
}
<form name="form01" action="">
  <label for="first-name">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-name" name="first-name" required>
  <p id="first-p">First name cannot be empty</p>
  <br>
  <label for="last-name">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required>
  <p id="last-p">Last name cannot be empty</p>
  <br>
  <label for="Email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
  <p id="email-p">Email cannot be empty</p>
  <br>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
  <p id="password-p">Password cannot be empty</p>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



